# My baby bunny having its own room

Tags: rabbits, containment

I have a new baby bunny and I have a 28" x 15.5" (71 x 39 cm) cage for him all set up and comfy just for him.

But I don't know if I want to keep him in the guest room or in my room. If he stays in my room, I'll have TV going and I don't know whether he would be happy in a living room or in a quiet room with lights on?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbits are social creatures and like to have stimulation and interaction in their lives. Without a companion rabbit, I would really recommend that he stays in the same room as you and that you get him out and about as much as possible. That cage is really quite small and, eventually, he's really going to outgrow it and need some space to roam, so getting your room ready is the best way to go. It's not that hard to bunny proof a single room and they can be litter trained.

Comment: Related [Is a bedroom enough space for a bunny to be happy?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8122) and [How do you bunny proof behind the couch?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1998)