# How dangerous are lemons for a cat?

Tags: cats, safety, eating

My 6 month old cat licked at a lemon slice but is behaving normally.

I've read on multiple websites that lemon is poisonous to cats (and dogs). However there are also some people that [recommend to rub citrus peels against cords](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/5671) to prevent the cats from biting them. Indicating that lemons aren't poisonous.

That made me wondering are lemons really poisonous to cats or just some parts like the peel or the seeds? How much would cause serious problems to a cat?

Below are a few links that state that lemons are poisonous:

- [ASPCA](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/toxic-and-non-toxic-plants/lemon)
- [All Pet Magazine](https://allpetmagazine.com/can-cats-eat-oranges-what-about-lemons/)
- [Wagwalking](https://wagwalking.com/cat/condition/lemon-poisoning)

Comment: Re-read your link to ASPCA: fruits are save, plants are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've read, lemon is poisonous, but it requires excessive amounts before it is really harmful. A single lick isn't going to do anything noticeable. Symptoms include vomiting, diarrhea, and contact dermatitis. I've found no references to any worse symptoms. Those symptoms, while unpleasant, aren't likely to cause lasting harm. The peels are worse than the fruit for cats.

https://www.cuteness.com/article/citrus-fruits-poisonous-cats

Comment: lemons contains suggar and cats are not able to taste sweet so i think that if a cat tries to eat lemon it will be a bad experience only tasting the acid and not the rest of the taste.