# Is bitter nail polish safe for cats?

Tags: cats, safety, chewing

I've been having real trouble with my cats chewing on cords. I've heard lots of people talking about bitter apple spray, but it seems like it would be better if I could paint something onto the cord itself that deters chewing rather than having to respray regularly. Is that bitter tasting nail polish that people use to break the habit of chewing their fingernails cat safe?

Comment: remedies to stop nailbiting do often contain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucrose_octaacetate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denatonium bothe chemicals are used to keep animals from eating or drinking dangerous chemicals.i am not sure about the safety so i made this a comment.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [How do I stop my cat from biting cords?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5667/12501). It contains several alternatives to bitter apple and nail polish. If you accept any answer of the linked question, please give me a shout so I can close this question as duplicate (that keeps the site clean and helps other users finding the most helpful answers quicker).

Comment: @Elmy There are several great anti-chewing strategies at the question you linked, but it doesn't really answer the safety question about the nail polish. I don't think that particular question has been asked at this site before. So maybe this shouldn't be closed after all?

Comment: @Empiromancer Sorry, you're right. I just quickly scanned the text and read "chewing cords" and immediately thought that it's a duplicate. But the core of your question is about bitter nail polish, not how to stop a cat from chewing cords.