# How to get a cat to stop chewing on cords?

Tags: cats, behavior, training

Title says it all. Is there some way to get a cat to stop chewing on cords. I have a lot of corded things lying around and my cat likes to play with them. He crawls under my computer desk and bats my phone charger cord out of my phone and I even catch him chewing on my snake thermostats sometimes. Is there some way to discourage or outright prevent this behavior?

Comment: Electrical wires and rabbits don't do well together, here are some related questions that might help [Why do rabbits chew electrical wires?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/358), [Make wires unpalatable?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5987) & [How do you bunny proof behind the couch?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1998)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rubbed lemon juice on my cat's favorite cords and that seems to have deterred the behavior, but I'm not sure if it's due to the lemon or that he's just moved on. Supposedly, cats hate citrus. "Critter cords" may help in the meantime (plastic cord covers that slip over chargers, etc. and prevent the cat's teeth from doing damage).

If there's a certain area he likes, maybe try a Sssscat. (It's a motion-activated can of compressed air that usually scares the life out of the cat). Has worked to keep my cat off of the counter, it may work to keep yours away from the thermostat area.

Comment: that can of air idea is interesting. I may use that for my snake cages or counter. I had this idea earlier this week before I saw this and tried rubbing a mild jalapeno juice on my mac cord and he has left it alone for two days so i think the general idea works. I probably should have used lemon juice so i wouldnt hurt my cat if the peppers were too hot or something but i didnt know about the citrus thing. I may try that for other cords in the future

Comment: also going to best answer this for now

Answer (score 1):

I had success in preventing my cat from chewing cords by putting my hand between her head and the cord whenever I saw that the wanted to chew on it, repeatedly. That means sometimes 5 times in a row, until she made at least a small pause before trying again. If it took several tries until she stopped I offered her a more interesting game with a moving string or something when she stopped. In general playing regularly with playing rods also reduced her interest on those non-moving cords.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any magic solution beyond saying "no", taking the inappropriate toy away or moving the cat, and giving them something better to play with...